# Android Paths - how to draw union of two paths?

Tags: java, android, graphics

Hi I'm creating simple drawing app on android and I want to create the app which will help user to draw more clear pictures.

For example, without any additional work user can create images like showed on picture #2.

I want to combine different Path's and:

1) Combine two path if these two patch are orthogonal and the end of one of them is nearest of the other path

2) Remove extra part of the path if it is intersects with other path.

In the result user should see the picture #1.

[image]

I've created the code like this but it doesn't do what I want:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < paths.size(); i++) {

        Path p1 = paths.get(i);

        Region region1 = new Region();
        region1.setPath(p1, clip);
        Region region2 = new Region();
        region2.setPath(mPath, clip);

        if (region1.op(region2, Region.Op.INTERSECT)) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                p1.op(mPath, Path.Op.UNION);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't think you can have it work that way. Informally, you want to look at the segments located at the ends of your paths, and look whether they falls within some distance (threshold) to the other paths, and if so, snap them to their projections on these paths. Using regions won't help, as they only represent _bounding boxes_ for the paths.

Comment: Probably regions is the wrong way but what is the right way here then?

Comment: I outlined the algorithm above, you should be able to implement it, or at least to give it a try. I don't think it would help you to give you the answer straight away. Besides, it's not the purpose of this site, we're here to help you debug your code, not write it for you.

Comment: didierc, for #1 from the list I've implemented the logic which you suggested, it works now. Thank you!

But it is still not clear how to implement requirement #2 from the list. - ok, we can track all points but how we will track intersections and how we will remove extra parts of Path?

Comment: I tried to use Path.setLastPoint  to resolve #2, but it doesn't work as I expected..

Comment: That is odd: snapping the ends of a path to those close enough should do the trick, whether the paths cross or not.